# Update variable tied to Behavior Subject without updating the Behavior Subject

Tags: angular

I have a behavior subject that takes a User object defined like this:

```
userObservable = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
```

I then have a function that gets the current value of it, makes some changes to local variable and POST the changes but I don't want to change the value of the Behavior Subject:

```
const newUser = this.userDetailsObservable.getValue()
newUser.fName = 'John'

this.sendData(newUser)
```

In doing this, the Behavior Subject changes without me calling .next(). How do I make local changes to a variable of a behavior subject without actually changing the behavior subject?

Comment: That is simply not true. `getValue` does Not change the BehaviorSubjects value. There must be more truth around your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValue()` doesn't change the value of behavior subject. it could have been changed in `sendData`. You can create a new instance of your object to not have any reference and check if it is still changing

you can use spread

`const newUser = {...this.userDetailsObservable.getValue()}`

or you can use old classic way as

`const newUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.userDetailsObservable.getValue()));`